# Creating a "new album" window

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

How can I call/create a "new album" window (the window that has a preview of images and some options) using VBA code? I'm using PowerPoint 2007 or 2010.

I am not asking how to import images into slides but how to display the "new album" window using VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PhotoAlbumInsert")

Comment: thank you! it works! one more thing, can you tell me how to set Files and Photo Layout while calling the "PhotoAlbumInsert"?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible other than perhaps by using SendKeys

Comment: Thank you! I don't like "sendkeys" but this seems to be the only choice I got.

Comment: Nobody likes sendkeys.  ;-)